# ios: How to create two differnent views from one view in IB?

Tags: ios, uiview, interface-builder

I created a custom UIView in Intefacebuilder. In my ViewController I want to create two instances of my UIViews.

So here is some code:

```
@interface MeineFinanzenViewController : UIViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate> {

UISwipeGestureRecognizer* swipeLeft;
UISwipeGestureRecognizer* swipeRight;

//... other stuff

SaldoView* ausgabenView;
SaldoView* einnahmenView;

}

//...other stuff
@property (strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet SaldoView* ausgabenView;
@property (strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet SaldoView* einnahmenView;
//...other stuff
```

So I connected the same view two times. Firstly to ausgabenView and secondly to einnahmenView.  BUT after that the ausgabenView becomes the same object as einnahmenView. Actually I would like to have two separated objects that are independent from each other. Now I'm asking myself how to achieve this?

Any hints?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are creating your views by editing your nib files graphically - as it seems you are - then if you want two views, then you drag two views onto the editor from the library.  You then connect one to each outlet.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I don't understand correctly. Do you mean I should connect my single SaldoView in IB two time. Once to ausgabenView and once to einnahmenView? Because this is exactly what I did and which does not work.

Comment: If you have a single `SaldoView` in Interface Builder, presumably you dragged a `UIView` onto your nib, you changed the class to `SaldoView`, then you connected it to two outlets?  Only connect it to one outlet.  Then do everything again for a second view.  Connect that to the other outlet.

Comment: Yeah, and that would mean twice the work. I doubt that that would be necessary.

Comment: Well okay, copy and paste works fine in that case. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: If you are creating your views graphically, then you already know you create a view by dragging it on.  The outlets are only pointers to that view.  Connecting it to more than one outlet just means more than one pointer to the same object.  If you want two views, and you are doing it graphically, drag two views on.

Answer (score 1):

You should load your view manually:

```
- (SaldoView *)loadCustomView {

    NSArray* nibViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NibFileName" owner:nil options:nil];
    for (id object in nibViews) {
        if ([object isKindOfClass:[SaldoView class]]) {
            return (SaldoView *)object;
        }
    } 
    return nil;
}
```

And create two instance of views

```
    SaldoView* ausgabenView = [self loadCustomView];
    SaldoView* einnahmenView = [self loadCustomView];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but mmhh I'm using a storyboard. How would I do that in that case?

Comment: I think that in your case it's no difference